# Add default value to an array when found a nil

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5

I'm trying to append some values to an array. The problem is that some values are nils, and when I try to fetch the array it returns an error:

This is my main code:

```
class ViewVerPedidos: UIViewController{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableOrders: UITableView!
    
    var originOrders = [String]()

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableOrders.dataSource = self
        tableOrders.delegate = self

        obtOrders()
  }


func obtOrders(){
        
        NetworkingProvider.shared.getAllOrders{ (pedidos) in
            
            for pedido in pedidos{
                self.originOrders.append(pedido.origen!) // <-This could be nil or not
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async{ [weak self] in
                self?.tableOrders.reloadData()
            }
            
        } failure: { (error) in
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return
        }
    }

extension ViewVerPedidos: UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return lblOriginOrders.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      
        let cell = tableOrders.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewCellOrders", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellOrders
        cell!.lblOriginOrders.text = originOrders[indexPath.row] // Here mark error nil found!
        return cell!
    }
}

}
```

The error is because found a nil:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value

I have tried, those:

```
self.originOrders.append(pedido.origen ?? "nothing found")
```

for add some default value if found a nil, but this don't work

Some ideas about how to add some default value to an array when found a nil?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do need to add anything if the value is nil, do you need a fixed size array or something?

Comment: The error here looks to me like it’s the cell that is nil. After your line `let cell = …` do a `print(cell)`. What is the output. (Or set a breakpoint and try it).

Comment: You really should never use forced unwrapping like this. Much better/safer to use an if let binding. Or guard let.

Comment: Why does `getAllOrders` return `nil` items at all? A better way is to filter the array before passing it in the closure.

Comment: @vadian oh, I just noticed there are two places commented in the code. The comments appear to show the second one (almost the last line) is causing the actual error.

Comment: @Fogmeister Right, but at least with a non-optional array the location of the error is not ambiguous 

Comment: @vadian yeah absolutely. I just didn’t see that particular code until you pointed it out.  but yeah, you’re right. Ideally the api shouldn’t return nil orders. But if it does just compact them out.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you append the results to the new array you could use this instead…

```
self.originOrders.append(contentsOf: pedidos.compactMap(\.origen))
```

This will map the array onto the `Origen` property and remove any that are nil. No need to do the `for pedido in pedidos…`.

I think your error is coming from how you are creating the cell though. Have you definitely registered the correct type of cell in your table view?

You need to use this api… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register

Inside your `viewDidLoad` function.

`tableOrders.register(TableViewCellOrders.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: “tableViewOrdersCell”)`

Comment: I guess the outlet is not connected. Registering a cell can cause confusion if the cells are just prototype cells (which we don’t know).

Comment: My idea was to fetch an array, and when a nil is found, the put a default value. I have resolved the problem with conditional: "if pedido.origen != nil || pedido.origen != "" ... In this way it's work, but i think this mustn't be the most elegant way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
var x : [String?] = ["lorum","ipsem",nil]
func myFunc(){
    let y = x.map{$0 ?? "Default"}
    print(y)
}
```

Result: ["lorum", "ipsem", "Default"]